# Vlan and Switch setting - dummy

Tags: networking, vlan, network-monitoring

I need to speak tomorrow the network engineer and I would like to understand his so apologise for the Dummy question:

In the school we have a cab with a 24 port Netgear manageable switch with an admin and curriculum VLAN settings.

Usually, as I over heard, in the morning and around 4.30pm there are a slowdown period on the computers which connect to this switch.

No one could track this back yet. Questions:

- What is the best way to track back this slowdown
- Would it be a temporary solution to physical separate the two network with 2 switches
- If that would work how can I link them together to be able to see the curriculum from the admin side.
- Do I need an extra router then?

Too many questions but I have no clue where to start and the gentleman will be paid by hours... can you see where I am coming from?:)

Could you guide me in the right direction please? Any comment would be appreciated and please send links if you down vote the question:)

Update: It turned out that one room could not get IP addresses after deploying OS to them so it was overloaded? The server was idle with an 5% in the other room. Needs to find out the IP addresses of the switches and see what are the settings. So we can see what went wrong.

thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Exact duplicate question of http://superuser.com/questions ?

Comment: correct I am keen to get an answer or just a hint on this as a matter of urgency sorry about that some people does not read superuser forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general, so we can't provide specific solution, though:

> What is the best way to track back this slowdown

Use a Monitoring tool to see how is the load at this time.

> Would it be a temporary solution to physical separate the two network with 2 switches

Of course you can use 2 switches.

> If that would work how can I link them together to be able to see the curriculum from the admin side

Again, your information is not clear. How the communication is established already? you use a router? The switch is a layer-3 one and acts as a router?

> Do I need an extra router then?

if it's a temporary solution, can't you switch back to Layer-2 and check if Layer-3 (routing) operations is the problem?

Comment: thank you for your effort, really appreciated!!! Answers at this moment VLAN is acting as two separate network they can't see each other bat that is the plan. I will check tomorrow morning the type of the switch. I guess it is Layer-3 switch.

Comment: What monitoring tool would you recommend as a fast tracking tool? preferable a free would be good:)

Comment: For Monitoring: if you have time for reading brief manual I recommend MRTG. If not, I recommend PRTG that has a straightforward UI. download freeware one. In both cases, you need to introduce switch by IP and SNMP community (as username/pass). they use SNMP for getting information. SNMP isn't difficult. It is possible that there is a corrupted NIC in your network. If you see spikes in PRTG graphs for one port, you can find it.